# Can Helm (v3) create apiVersion 1 charts?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have Helm v3.2.1.

When I run `helm create foo`, Helm creates charts that use `apiVersion: v2` and the associated file structure (e.g. no `requirements.yaml`)

Is there some way to inform Helm that I would like it to create apiVersion v1 type charts?

Information I have seen to date is orientated only on migrating from API version 1 to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can create Helm 2 charts using Helm 3. It is possible to migrate Helm 2 to Helm 3 using [this](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/v2_v3_migration/). For generating Helm 2 charts you will need Helm 2.